# What is a CB Number™?

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

*This puzzle is based off the What is a Word™, What is a Phrase™ and What is a Number™ series started by JLee.*

If a number conforms to a certain rule, I call it a CB Number™. Use the following examples to find the rule:

| CB Numbers™ | Non-CB Numbers™ |
| --- | --- |
| 383 | 384 |
| 1412 | 1214 |
| 7557 | 8557 |
| 49537 | 43579 |
| 84286 | 86420 |
| 310222 | 420333 |
| 629218 | 639318 |
| 1234511 | 5432111 |
| 4762129 | 4763239 |
| 22222530 | 33333520 |
| 63655555 | 36355555 |
| 89899898 | 89898989 |

Here is a CSV:

```
CB Numbers™,Non-CB Numbers™
383,384
1412,1214
7557,8557
49537,43579
84286,86420
310222,420333
629218,639318
1234511,5432111
4762129,4763239
22222530,33333520
63655555,36355555
89899898,89898989
```

The puzzle relies on the series' inbuilt assumption, that each number can be tested for whether it is a CB Number™ own its own. In particular, a number's relationship to other numbers in the sequence is irrelevant.

These are not the only examples of CB Numbers™, more can be found.

The only reason the Non-CB Numbers™ are not in ascending order is because I have tried to make them look similar to the corresponding CB Numbers™ to their left. Note that this doesn't change the puzzle.

Comment: CB Numbers™ aren't reliant on an obscure property of numbers like my previous question on weird numbers.

Comment: are the letter's 'CB' significant, or are they arbitrary?

Comment: If they're arbitrary, I think they'd be the first puzzle of this sort in which the name had no significance at all.

Comment: @Pat They aren't arbitrary - they are of some significance, though they probably won't allow you to easily solve the puzzle. More that if you solve the puzzle in the way I intended, you would have a second point of conformation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

CB Numbers are numbers that

> If you treat each digit as weights, the whole number balances on the midpoint of the scale.

For example,

> in the number 1412, let us visualise as 1-4^1-2 where ^ indicates the midpoint. It can be observed that the distance-to-center of an outer digit is 3 times that of the inner digit.

We have,

> the sum of weight times distance-to-center (left) = 1*3 + 4*1 = 7
>  the sum of weight times distance-to-center (right) = 1*1 + 2*3 = 7
>  Hence, 1412 balances on the midpoint.

CB probably stands for

> Centrally balanced.